# How many types of payment systems we can integrate to buy game levels through third party in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, payment-gateway, game-center

I want to integrate any third party In-App Sales credit systems in my small gaming application. In my application,there is some game levels. I want to  give some levels of gaming as free, after some levels, user should be purchase levels. So, please suggest me which process is better for integrating third party credit payment systems in my gaming application with out using Apple default In-App purchase feature. Is it possible to do like this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not allowed to do this under App Store rules, but I'll let someone who's absolutely sure put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the App Store Review Guidelines, section 11 (I won't reproduce it here).  If you use anything other than Apple's in-app purchase API your app will be rejected.  Even the biggest companies (e.g. Amazon) don't get around this rule.  The only way you might get around it would be to handle all payments outside the app, such as on a website, and then link the app to the website.  No guarantees that Apple wouldn't reject your app anyway though.